# create custom validator for multiple different POJOs with same attributes java spring

Tags: java, spring, validation

I have 3 different POJOs all of them share 2 same attributes.  (user and group)
I need to create a custom validator what checks if those 2 attributes are OK (if user actually belongs to group).
Currently I am doing checks before calling any other methods.. But I'd like to implement custom @annotation constraint. I know how to create it for single class but I am lost in how to do it for multiple different classes.

Answer (score 0):

One way:

Create an interface that has two methods getUser() and getGroup(), make all your POJOs implement that interface and then write your @annotation to validate that interface.